# SQL select query for 3 tables and put result into one array incrementing by one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a sql Select from one table and then sql select from second table and then put the results inside the same array.

The original SQL query which I am using is the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT users.*, cursos.titulo, subscriptions.status
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN subscriptions
ON users.userID = subscriptions.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN cursos
ON cursos.id = subscriptions.curso_id";
```

[image]

Which is pulling all the data from table users and then getting data from table cursos based on the values of the table subscriptions.
This way the query works like pulling the same data from table users depending on how many times the user id can be found inside the subcriptions table. Let's say if the subscriptions table contains

```
curso_id | user_id 
14       | 48
12       | 48
```

in this case it will be generated 2 arrays each of them will contains all the data from users and than the data from cursos.

So my question is how I can make a SQL query which will fist execute SELECT * FROM Users , after this is complete for the first row in the table I would like to execute a second query  which will be something like this:

```
SELECT users.id, cursos.titulo, subscriptions.status
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN subscriptions
ON users.userID = subscriptions.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN cursos
ON cursos.id = subscriptions.curso_id
```

And put all the information inside one variable for titulo and inside another variable for status. In this case this information can be various results so it should be divided by comma or space but the important is to be loaded inside the same cell of the array.

This operation will generate an array in which will contains 1 row per user containing all the user data columns and 2 more columns for titulo and status for which columns each row of them should contains various results pulled from the cursos table, depending on how many times time user id in this case "48" is seen inside the subscription table. The goal is this information of titluo and status to be put on a single cell, no matter how many results there are for it inside the cursos table. Any help will be welcome.

So the final result array shuld looks like this: [image]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading that correctly, you'll have to build your data array a bit differently than normal. e.g. most people have

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $data[] = $row;
}
```

If you want to ADD to that array from another query, you would have to key the array with the specific fields which are common between both queries, e.g.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $key1 = $row['key1'];
   $key2 = $row['key2'];
   etc...
   $data[$row1][$row2][....][] = $row;
}
```

Then use those same keys from your next query, e.g.

```
SELECT key1, key2, ...

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($other_result)) {
   $key1 = $row['key1']
   ...
   $data[$row1][$row2][....][] = $row;
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if this can be completed by a single query, and sorting all the information inside a single array at once. but I will investigate your answer as well.

Comment: probably. whenever you've got 2 queries and the second query uses data from the first query to execute, they can almost always be rewritten as a single `JOIN`ed query.